# AngularJS Nested IF

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add a bit of logic to my controller with a couple of nested If statements. By themselves they work fine, but after nesting them, i'm not getting any results.

This is a working statement:

```
            if (typeof object["Frequency"]!='undefined' && object["Frequency"]=='yearly' && ('now' <= 'upcoming')) {
            $scope.summary[segment].totalLateRelationships++;
            $scope.summary[segment].lateRelationships.push(object);
        }
```

This is working:

```
            if (!(object["nextmeetingowner"].length) || !(object["nextmeetingowner"].length) ) {
                $scope.summary[segment].totalLateRelationships++;
                $scope.summary[segment].lateRelationships.push(object);
            }
```

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
            if (!(object["primaryaccountability"].length) || (!(object["nextmeetingowner"].length))) {
          if  (typeof object["Frequency"]!='undefined' && object["Frequency"]=='yearly' && ('now' <= 'upcoming'))
            {
                $scope.summary[segment].totalLateRelationships++;
                $scope.summary[segment].lateRelationships.push(object);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

That third code block is checking something different than the first two. It's evaluating

```
!(object["primaryaccountability"].length)
```

...whereas the earlier code is evaluating

```
!(object["Last Meeting Date"].length)
```

Comment: I don't think that last update was what you intended it to be.